# Error executing command in bash

Tags: mysql, regex, linux, perl, bash

When executing an echo on a bash script like this:

```
(echo mysql --host=${host} --user=${user} --password=${password} ${database} '<'  '${i// /\\ }' )
```

I get the "correct" line echoed to the terminal... however when I remove the echo I get MySQL errors. The problem is I can't see exactly what is being sent to mysql, but it seems to be different than what I see when I do the echo... any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in a bash script, then change the first line to

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

This will execute the script in debug mode and allow you to see expansion of all the variables.

The input redirection '<' should not be in quotes, and neither should the input source. Even without the quotes I don't think that the input source will expand to what you want it to be.

Try creating your input source string before using it in the mysql command.

```
declare input=${i// /\\ }
```

Use eval

```
eval mysql --host=${host} --user=${user} --password=${password} ${database} < ${input}
```

eval will expand all variables before attempting to execute the command.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should remove the single quotes around `<` and `${i// /\\ }` when trying to execute the command. When executing you have to treat these as the appropriate tokens rather than merely as strings.